# MySQL: Count the number of consecutive times a value appears

Tags: mysql, sql

I've done a bit of Googling to try and find this answer and even came across the OVER() function for SQL Server and an article on how to emulate...but it's above my pay grade :P

I'll keep it simple and say I have a table of students and an action column. I want to create a query that will count the number of consecutive times that they either raised their hand, didn't raise their hand, or didn't attend class.  There are no weekend classes, so it has to count the actual records, not just today-FirstFoundDate.  If student A raises their hand for 3 weeks straight (that count would be 15=5days X 3weeks) but then doesn't show up to class, the count will be 0.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Please show your table schema.

Comment: The above was a metaphor, my actual table schema doesn't match the example and would confuse the question.  So...

CREATE TABLE tblActions
 StudentID AS INT,
 Action AS INT,
 Date AS DATE
END

Comment: It will be also nice to see sample data and expected results.

Comment: Student - Action - Date
John - UP - 1/1/2013
John - UP - 1/2/2013
John - UP - 1/3/2013
Mary - DOWN - 1/1/2013
Mary - UP - 1/2/2013

Result:
John - 3
Mary - 1

Sorry, I'm new on this board and haven't quite figured out the formatting thing yet.

Comment: For a given student, are we guaranteed that for every school day we will have a record with `Action` that it is **not** `NULL` or could their be gaps?

Comment: No, that gaurantee doesn't exist.  It's possible that the teacher didn't make a record of the results for that day, in which case we want to assume that the non-existent record has the same value as the day before it (so that the counting isn't reset).

Comment: @Bodi K-you should always create sample data and not expect someone do this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been thinking about this, and let's start over...

How about

```
select *
from student_action maindata
where not exist (select * from student_action action_count
                 where maindata.student_id = action_count.student_id
                   and maindata.action_timestamp < action_count.action_timestamp
                   and maindata.action <> action_count.action)
```

This should give us all the consecutive actions in the table, one row for each consecutive occurrence.  Then the group by will count them.

```
select count(*), maindata.student_id, maindata.action
from student_action maindata
where not exist (select * from student_action action_count
                 where maindata.student_id = action_count.student_id
                   and maindata.action_timestamp < action_count.action_timestamp
                   and maindata.action <> action_count.action)
group by maindata.student_id, maindata.action
```

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you Marlin, this worked perfectly!  
(I can't up vote this because I'm not cool enough yet lol)